# Bean Validation: Does @Digits validator support Double?

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

In the Bean Validation spec ( both version [JSR 303](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/) and [JSR 349](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/) ) and [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/beanvalidation/spec/1.1/api/), both don't mention anything about @Digits support for Double or Float types. It only says it supports the following types:

- BigDecimal
- BigInteger
- CharSequence
- byte, short, int, long, and their respective wrapper types

However, I tested it many times against Double fields in  my entities and I found that it works well!

Does it have any drawbacks that I can not see? Is it discouraged to use it with Double?

Also I found the documentation does explicitly say that [@Min](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/beanvalidation/spec/1.0/api/javax/validation/constraints/Min.html) and [@Max](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/beanvalidation/spec/1.0/api/javax/validation/constraints/Max.html) don't support Double and Float. However, It is not that clear about the [@Digits](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/beanvalidation/spec/1.0/api/javax/validation/constraints/Digits.html)

Comment: 'I tested it many times against Double fields in my entities and I found that it does work well!' You mean It does NOT work ( exception ) or Work but not properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate Validator actually supports `@Digits` on any `Number` type and thus also for `Double`/`double`. This is done by creating a `BigDecimal` from the string representation of the given number. As this behavior is not mandated by the spec, it might not be working with other Bean Validation providers.

Answer (score 1):

Double is a floating point number and can't describe decimal numbers very well. When rounding errors occur and the number of fraction digits can change.